# Read from NTX files with Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, indexing, oledb, dbf, dbase

I'm trying to read from some DBF files that use NTX files for indexing within VB.NET. Currently, I'm having to read directly from the DBF files using OLEDB, which is ridiculously slow due to dbase's flat file method of data storage. So, I'm wondering if someone could tell me how to access the DBF files through their NTX index files within VB.NET.

If I need to download a third party library I'm okay with that, But I don't have money to pay for a third party library if it costs money. It would need to be free.

This is what I'm currently using to access the DBF Files.

```
Private Shared ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.DataPath & ";Extended Properties=dBase IV"
Public Shared dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM `PAGES.NTX` WHERE `PAGE_NUM` BETWEEN 241 AND 270", dBaseConnection)
Dim dBaseDataReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dBaseCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
```

This however still reads directly from the DBF file and ignores the NTX indexing. Any help?

Note: I cannot "choose" to use SQL for this project as the DataBases are ones created and maintained by another application (One of considerable age). I need only access them for the data stored within.

Comment: Of course you can choose to use SQL Server.   SQL Server has a feature called Linked Servers, which will allow you to "host" your DBF files within a SQL Server instance.

Comment: @SamAxe I can't run a separate server due to PCI compliance. I need to work only with the files at my disposal and a local instance of VB.NET.

Comment: [Advantage OLEDB provider for ADO.NET](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/mergedProjects/adsoledb/adsoledb/connection_string_parameters_(advantage_ole_db_provider).htm) claims to talk to DBF/NTX files.

Comment: Couldn't you import the records into an sql Local database file?

Comment: @I'mStartingToHateThisSite The files would be being updated real time. So, I feel like that would severely effect performance.

Comment: I don't understand why this question got down-voted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Advantage .NET Data Provider](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=19&Product=4&Platform=11)

This is the only example I could find.  Since I do not have the files to test with this is only an example:

```
    'Set the TypeTable to NTX
    Dim conn As New AdsConnection("data source=c:\data;" + "ServerType=remote|local; TableType=NTX")
    Dim cmd As AdsCommand
    Dim reader As AdsDataReader
    Dim iField As Integer

    Try

        ' make the connection to the server
        conn.Open()

        ' create a command object
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand()

        ' specify a simple SELECT statement
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from departments"

        ' execute the statement and create a reader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        ' dump the results of the query to the console
        While reader.Read()
            For iField = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                Console.Write(reader.GetValue(iField) + " ")
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        End While

        conn.Close()
    Catch e As AdsException
        ' print the exception message
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: I'll give this a try when I'm home from work and let you know if it works out

Comment: So, I've go that library working. However, I'm pretty sure it's not looking at the index files by default. So, Is there a way to define what index it uses?

Comment: According to their help files:
To get support for creating and opening NTX index files, create a database (defined in a data dictionary) and add the tables and the associated NTX index files to that database. Then use those tables on that database connection. The NTX index files will then get automatically opened when the corresponding DBF table is opened. You can use the Advantage Data Architect to create a database and data dictionary.

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/mergedProjects/bdp-net/bdp_net/advantage_bdp_net_connection_options.htm

Comment: This is the only example I could find it is not in VB but you should be able to translate it into VB.NET
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?ade_addindexfile.htm

Comment: Thanks for all the help @EJD. Hopefully I can get it working with this information :)

Comment: I'm unable to find the AdsDictionary class in the library that was provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any reason to keep the data within these DBF files ?   Why just recreate the database in MySQL and export all the data into MySQL ?

Comment: I'm not the one creating the database. I'm putting together an application that will interface with the data. The data is managed by a third party application that is rather old. My application simply needs to look at the data. Which it already does. But, I'm unable to get any of these database drivers to load the NTX index files so it takes ages to go through all of the data. Also, I'm pretty sure that the ADS functions are only related to ADS databases. Not DBF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84830/discussion-between-ejd-and-thefiscster510).